# how can I get a variable with all the results and iterate over it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I have a table with some records, about 40, called Table1.

I would like to create a new register in another table for each these records, but I don't know how can I do it. I would like to iterate with a while loop for each record and insert the record in the other table, but I don't how (the syntax).

I would like something like this:

```
foreach record in myTable1
     Insert into Table2(IDTable1) VALUES(record.IDTable1)
end foreach
```

I don't know scripts in SQL Server.

Thanks.

Comment: here is example http://stackoverflow.com/a/5182076/1692632

Comment: INSERT INTO Table2 (IDTable1) SELECT IDTable1 FROM myTable1

Comment: Iterating over a cursor is the worst performance killer for any database. You can almost always create an `INSERT ... FROM ` statement that does the same job, only in 1/1000 of the time (at least).

Comment: You don't (generally/if you can avoid it) loop in SQL. You write a query that describes the entire, overall goal, and let the database system work out how best to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only insertion, you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (IDTable1)
SELECT IDTable1 FROM myTable1
```

It will select all `IDTable1` from `myTable1` and insert them into `Table2`.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server, for the most part, is set-based. That means that queries and rows are down in sets, group and filtered by clauses. Only in rare cases will you want or need to iterate over every single row in a result set and do something with it.

I'd say in your case, you're wanting to copy the contents of one table to another. You can do that several ways, but one of the easiest is something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  IDTable1
INTO
  Table2
FROM
  Table1
```

This assumes that `Table2` does not exist, and will create it. If `Table2` already exists, your syntax will change to be like what other answers indicated:

```sql
INSERT INTO Tabel2( IDTable1 )
SELECT
  IDTable1
FROM
  Table1
```